# Azure Media Player Enable Seeker and other controls

Tags: html, azure, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I am trying to integrate Azure Media Player into the project using HTML/JS code snippets. But I am unable to enable the rewind and forward buttons. Even the arrow keys are not working.
I also want to enable more features like captions etc. Any code snippet(s) or documentation will be of great help.

Currently, I am referring to the following https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/index.html
to make a breakthrough.

Thanks

Below is the code snippet
`

```
<video id="azuremediaplayer" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered"> </video>
    <script>
        var myOptions = {
            autoplay: true,
            controls: true,
            width: "640",
            height: "400",
            poster: "",
            cea708CaptionsSettings: {
                enabled: true,
                srclang: 'en',
                label: 'Live CC'
            },
            playbackSpeed: {
                enabled: true,
                initialSpeed: 1.0,
                speedLevels: [
                    { name: "x4.0", value: 4.0 },
                    { name: "x3.0", value: 3.0 },
                    { name: "x2.0", value: 2.0 },
                    { name: "x1.75", value: 1.75 },
                    { name: "x1.5", value: 1.5 },
                    { name: "x1.25", value: 1.25 },
                    { name: "normal", value: 1.0 },
                    { name: "x0.75", value: 0.75 },
                    { name: "x0.5", value: 0.5 },
                ]
            },
            plugins: {
                hotkeys: {
                    //optional settings
                    "volumeStep": 0.1,
                    "seekStep": 2,
                    "enableMute": true,
                    "enableFullscreen": true,
                    "enableNumbers": true,
                    "enableJogStyle": true
                }
            }
        };
        var myPlayer = amp("azuremediaplayer", myOptions);
       
        myPlayer.src([{ src: "https://resources.blob.core.windows.net/staging/videos/test.mp4",  type: "video/mp4" }, ]);

    </script>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest having a look here [AMP Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/azure-media-player/azure-media-player-overview), there are a lot of samples [AMP Samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-media-player-samples) and demos [AMP Demos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/azure-media-player/demos)